# How to check and ensure SSH is accepting connections?

Tags: ssh

I was wondering how someone would check if SSH is accepting connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the netstat command to observe what is listening on each port:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~$ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1097/smbd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1327/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1097/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1362/apache2
tcp        0      0 192.168.111.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1235/named
tcp        0      0 my-external-ip:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1235/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1235/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1335/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1545/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1235/named
```

Observe the Secure Shell server daemon listening on port 22.

Comment: Thanks for the answer